# Load partial html with javascript inside

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

On my website I load html, which is rendered at the server (nodejs), and insert it at the right position (most time a div with id content).

How would I insert the received html on the client, so that included script tags are executed?

I am using on the client side underscore and handlebars. But vanillajs is also possible of course.

PS: Here is an example to show the difference between `jQuery.html()` and setting the `innerHTML`-property:

http://jsfiddle.net/waxolunist/VDYgU/3/

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825804/nodejs-ejs-partials-with-scripts-in-the-head and res.Render in http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.xhr

Comment: Could you elaborate on this. I don't get it.

Comment: You can render html with a callback responding. 

res.render('sometemplate', {layout: false});

Comment: But isn't res.render a serverside function, or how do I get the response object on the clientside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with jQuery

```
$('div#content').html(loaded_html);
```

without:

```
getElementById('content').innerHTML = loaded_html;
```

While possible to do it your way, a better idea might be to send json and render pages in the browser using the same templates you (possibly) use in the server. I'm using doT, which I think to be the best of all JavaScript based templates (like EJS, underscore).

Comment: Yes, I swiched to jquery before your answer already. It works actually different and so script get executed. InnerHTML does not work for me (Chrome 26). I accept your answer though. I am rendering the html serverside only in some cases not in all. On the client I am using depending on the use case handlebars.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage jQuery to do that.
Just with

$.load("#divname").load(url)

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: It loads the data into the DIV (innerHTML). It's a kind of sugar

Comment: I have on the client the html already. There is no url where the source resides. I load the content via websocket.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with your character escaping, please use `jshint`. Otherwise it is pretty simple to use like

```
var script1 = "content for jQuery";
var script2 = "content for javascript";

$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#content1').html(script1);
    document.getElementById('content2').innerHTML = script2;
})
```