# Executing JavaScript in partial html for single page navigation

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, partial

I am new to JavaScripts, and I'm attempting to build a single page navigation blog using bootstrap. I have a basic `index.html` which has the following code:

```
<Some bootstrap navbar on top that includes "home", "about", "contact">

<div id="content">
</div>

<script src="navigation.js"></script>
```

The `navigation.js` file  has a window.addEventListener("hashchange", navigate) that just listens for the hashchange and sets the `innerHTML` of the content-div based on the hash. The actual content for each of the pages is seperated into partial html files, for example `about.html` that only has `<p>About</p>` for now, and these partial htmls are fetched using AJAX.

So far everything works, but for the `home.html` I don't have only static HTML, i also want to execute a JavaScript that renders all the blog posts. Basically I would want `home.html` to include:

```
<div id="posts">
</div>
<script src="renderposts.js"></script>
```

Where `renderposts.js` is a script that sets the `innerHTML` of the posts-div to include all my blog posts.

This doesn't work though, `renderposts.js` is not executed. Am I thinking about this the wrong way and how should I approach this? The only work-around that I've managed is to include the code in the `navigation.js` file instead, and execute it with an if-statement checking if the location.hash is currently "#home". This is obviously a very ugly solution.

Comment: Does renderposts.js just have code that is executed when it's loaded, or is it a series of functions?

Comment: renderPosts has two functions ("getPosts" and "renderPosts") that are executed from within the file when it's loaded

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find this post when searching the topic but it appeared in the related section after posting: [Load partial html with javascript inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405034/load-partial-html-with-javascript-inside?rq=1)

Basically, changing from `contentDiv.innerHTML = content;` to jQuerys `$('div#content').html(content);` fixed the issue. I'm still curious whether this is the "correct" way to go about the principal issue, or if I'm approaching the whole thing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle it is to link renderposts.js from your main page, then in the function that loads home.html, it can then execute the javascript functions. Something like

```
<script src="navigation.js"></script>
<script src="renderposts.js"></script>
<button onclick="loadHome">Click Me</button>

<script>
    function loadHome() {
        // Some AJAX Requst Here //

        var contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");
        contentDiv.innerHTML = content;
        getPosts();
        renderPosts();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Excellent, I will play around with this. Thanks! (unfortunately my reputation score is too low to upvote, but your help is much appreciated!)